# What is the significance of Visual Studio Package File and how to use it?

Tags: visual-studio, solution-package, packaging

What is the significance of Visual Studio Package File and how to use it? See the image below.

[image]

Can any one provide an explanation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> You can use the Package Designer to create and customize a package
>   (.wsp). For example, you can add SharePoint project items and
>   Features, specify if the Web server is reset when the solution is
>   deployed, and set the deployment server type.

it contains all the files for deployment like xml, dll, wsp ect...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee231544(v=vs.100).aspx

for deployment follow this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee231544(v=vs.100).aspx

hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You can double-click on the Package.package file and see in the designer what you can do with it (for instance, change what features and mapped folders to deploy).

Comment: I am not able to see the designer, but package file is there. Do you have any idea about how to get the designer file back? @MikhailSP